# Strong Maximum Principle for the heat Equation - Evans - Theorem 4 - Why do we need U to be bounded.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I had a doubt in following theorem of Evans

THEOREM 4 (Strong maximum principle). Suppose $u \in C^2_1(U) \cap C(\bar{U})$ is satisfies $u_t + \Delta u = 0$ within $U_T$. (i) Then
$$
\max _{\bar{U_T}} u=\max _{\Gamma_T} u
$$
(ii) Furthermore, if $U$ is connected and there exists a point $(x_0, t_0) \in U_T$ such that
$$
u\left(x_0,t_0\right)=\max _{\bar{U_T}} u
$$
then $u$ is constant within $\bar{U_{t_0}}$.

Assertion (i) is the maximum principle for heat's equation and (ii) is the strong maximum principle.

Proof (as in Evans) -

1. Suppose there exists a point $(x_0, t_0) \in U_T$ with $u(x_0,t_0) = M := \max_{\bar{U_T}}u$ Then for all sufficiently small $r > 0$, $E(x_0,t_0;r) \in U_T$; and we employ the mean value property to deduce that $$ M = u(x_0,t_0) = \frac{1}{4r^n}\int\int_{E(x_0,t_0;r)} u(y,s) \frac{|x_0 - y|^2}{(t_0 -s)^2} \leq M $$ since $$ 1 = \frac{1}{4r^n}\int\int_{E(x_0,t_0;r)}  \frac{|x_0 - y|^2}{(t_0 -s)^2}$$

Equality holds only if $u$ is identitically equal to $M$ within $E(x_0,t_0;r)$. Consequently $$ u(y,s) = M \,\, \forall (y,s) \in E(x_0,t_0;r)$$

Draw any line segment $L$ in $U_T$ connecting $(x_0,t_0)$ with some other point $(y_0, s_0) \in U_T$ with $s_0 < t_0$. Consider $$ r_0 = \min\{s \geq s_0 : u(x,t) = M \text{for all points } (x,t) \in L \, s\leq t \leq t_0\}$$

Since $u$ is continous the minimum is attained. Assume $r_0 > s_0$. Then $u(z_0, r_0) = M$ for some point $(z_0, r_0)$ on $L \cap U_T$ and so $u \equiv M$ on $E(z_0,r_0;r)$ for all sufficently small $r>0$. Since $E(z_0,r_0;r)$ contains $L \cap \{r_0 - \sigma \leq t \leq r_0 + \sigma\}$
for some small $\sigma >0$, we have a contradiction. Thus $r_0 = s_0$ and hence $u \equiv M$ on $L$.

2. Now fix any point $x \in U$ and any time $0 \leq t \leq t_0$. There exists points $\{x_0,x_1, \cdots, x_m =x \}$ such that the line segment in $\mathbb{R}^n$ connecting $x_{i-1}$ to $x_i$ lie in $U$ for $i = 1, \cdots, m.$ Select times $t_0 > t_1 > \cdots > t_m =t$. Then the line segments in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ connecting $(x_{i-1}, t_{i-1})$ to $(x_i, t_i)$ lie in $U_T$. According to step 1, $u \equiv M$ on each such line segment and so $u(x,t) = M$

I can understand the general idea of the proof, which use representation formulae, and then shows that if maximum is attained in the parabolic cylinder then solution has to be constant.

**What I do not understand here is why do we need $U$ to be bounded and exactly where in the proof we use this. In time I think since we can do for any $t_0 \leq T$ we can take $T$ to be infinite, So I was trying to do something for space space variable also, but was not able to conclude anything**

Comment: Please include the mentioned proof.

Comment: @Akira - Added the proof

Comment: I am guessing it is because a continuous function on an unbounded domain need not have a maximum.